# Select portion of string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of data that contains full UNC paths to directories. I want to select just the path (removing the server/IPs). How can I do this?

Data:

```
\\nas.home.example.com\dvd\My First Video
\\nas.office.example.com\business\Report1
\\nas.office.example.com\business\Report2
\\10.10.10.10\projects\proj1\images
\\10.10.10.10\projects\proj1\queries
\\10.10.10.10\projects\proj1\output
```

Expected Results (can be with or without the leading `\`, I don't care):

```
\dvd\My First Video
\business\Report1
\business\Report2
\projects\proj1\images
\projects\proj1\queries
\projects\proj1\output
```

I've tried the following (specific to one of the above inputs):

```
SELECT RIGHT(('\\nas.home.example.com\dvd\My First Video'), 
  CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE('\\nas.home.example.com\dvd\My First Video')));
```

This returns just the inner most directory (`My First Video`). I can add an offset to get the parent, but it only works if the directory is exactly that number of characters:

```
SELECT RIGHT(('\\nas.home.example.com\dvd\My First Video'), 
  CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE('\\nas.home.example.com\dvd\My First Video'))+4);
```

Returns `\dvd\My First Video`, which is good - for that one value. How can I modify my query to work for all of my data values?

I suspect I may actually need two of these queries. One for the servers with a DNS name, that all end in `.com` and one for the IP address, which all start with `10.10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @x TABLE (p VARCHAR(255))

INSERT @x SELECT '\\nas.home.example.com\dvd\My First Video'
UNION ALL SELECT '\\nas.office.example.com\business\Report1'
UNION ALL SELECT '\\nas.office.example.com\business\Report2'
UNION ALL SELECT '\\10.10.10.10\projects\proj1\images'
UNION ALL SELECT '\\10.10.10.10\projects\proj1\queries'
UNION ALL SELECT '\\10.10.10.10\projects\proj1\output'
UNION ALL SELECT 'foo.bar\whatever\who';

SELECT p, x = SUBSTRING(p, CHARINDEX('\', SUBSTRING(p, 3, 4000)) + 2, 4000) FROM @x;
```

Results:

```
p                                           x
-----------------------------------------   ------------------------
\\nas.home.example.com\dvd\My First Video   \dvd\My First Video
\\nas.office.example.com\business\Report1   \business\Report1
\\nas.office.example.com\business\Report2   \business\Report2
\\10.10.10.10\projects\proj1\images         \projects\proj1\images
\\10.10.10.10\projects\proj1\queries        \projects\proj1\queries
\\10.10.10.10\projects\proj1\output         \projects\proj1\output
foo.bar\whatever\who                        \whatever\who
```

If you want to remove the leading `\`, change `+ 2` to `+ 3`.

Answer (score 1):

Same concept as Aaron, slightly different syntax

```
SUBSTRING(p, CHARINDEX('\',p,3), 255)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (the important part is the third line):

```
DECLARE @str varchar(100)
SET @str = '\\nas.home.example.com\dvd\My First Video'
select substring(@str, CHARINDEX('\', @str, 3), len(@str) - charindex('\', @str, 3))
```

Replace `@str` with the column name in your `SELECT` statement.

What this is doing is grabbing a substring of the string starting at the first index of '\' after the third character and having the length of the total length of the string minus the first index of '\' after the third.